# EE 2.11.8 update broke CartThrob 2.71

Tags: cartthrob

After I updated ExpressionEngine from 2.11.7 to 2.11.8, CartThrob 2.71's order items stopped recording numeric information such as the order item's price, subtotal, quantity, etc. However, the order totals are still being captured.

I did not make any other changes when updating EE, and when I rolled back EE to 2.11.7, CartThrob resumed working as it should.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a fix?

(PHP 5.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE 2.11.9 fixes the problem introduced in EE 2.11.8, and now CartThrob 2.71 is back to working as it was before.

https://expressionengine.com/blog/expressionengine-3.5.6-and-2.11.9-released

Comment: As you noted, this was an issue with ExpressionEngine's update itself which they've fixed in 2.11.9. I'm glad it's working for you now!